# Twitter data over https by using SDK emulator

Tags: security, android

I have installed SDK emulator and Twitter client to do research on traffic, I wanna know why Twitter client uses https while sending or receiving its tweets.
Is there any mechanism through which i can change https into http.
I want to analyze the traffic by using wire-shark. Kindly let men kow how i can achieve this

Comment: This is *not* a WordPress question ... at all ... migrating to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Twitter uses SSL to protect the data in transit...precisely to prevent folks from eavesdropping on it in transit as you are trying to do. The Twitter Android client (and all clients, AFAIK) uses SSL as part of their design and does not allow you disable SSL functionality.